# CloudFormation creation of CloudFront distribution with logging bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cloudformation

Trying to provision a static website bucket that's distributed by CloudFront.

The following CloudFormation template works if I omit the `Logging` configuration for the distribution:

```
{
...

"PrimeBucket": {
    "Properties": {
        "AccessControl": "PublicRead",
        "WebsiteConfiguration": {
            "ErrorDocument": "error.html",
            "IndexDocument": "index.html"
        }
    },
    "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket"
},
"PrimeBucketDistribution": {
    "Properties": {
        "DistributionConfig": {
            "DefaultCacheBehavior": {
                "AllowedMethods": [
                    "GET",
                    "HEAD",
                    "OPTIONS"
                ],
                "ForwardedValues": {
                    "QueryString": "false"
                },
                "TargetOriginId": "BucketOrigin",
                "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "allow-all"
            },
            "Enabled": "true",
            "Logging": {
                "Bucket": {
                    "Ref": "PrimeBucketLogs"
                },
                "IncludeCookies": "false"
            },
            "Origins": [
                {
                    "DomainName": {
                        "Fn::GetAtt": [
                            "PrimeBucket",
                            "DomainName"
                        ]
                    },
                    "Id": "BucketOrigin",
                    "S3OriginConfig": {}
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "Type": "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution"
},
"PrimeBucketLogs": {
    "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket"
}
}
```

If I include `Logging` I get the error:

`The parameter Logging Bucket does not refer to a valid S3 bucket.`

Is there any extra magic that needs to be applied to the logging bucket in order for it to be compatible with CloudFront? Couldn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out?

Comment: can't remember :(

Answer (score 26):

Try specifying your bucket name as `"bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com"` instead of just `"bucketname"`.

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer and should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Using Terraform, to avoid this error: `Error: error updating CloudFront Distribution InvalidArgument: The parameter Logging Bucket does not refer to a valid S3 bucket.`

You can workaround logging name if S3 bucket is created in the same code:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_s3_sample" {
  bucket        = "simple-application"
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "my_cloudfront_sample" {
...
..
  logging_config {
    include_cookies = true
    bucket =  "${aws_s3_bucket.my_s3_sample.id}.s3.amazonaws.com"
    prefix          = "logs/cloudfront/my_cloudfront_sample/"
  }
}
```

Or importing S3 with Datasource

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "selected" {
  bucket = "simple-application"
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "my_cloudfront_sample" {
...
..
  logging_config {
    include_cookies = true
    bucket =  "${data.aws_s3_bucket.selected.id}.s3.amazonaws.com"
    prefix          = "logs/cloudfront/my_cloudfront_sample/"
  }
}
```